# Wrong coordinates from TransformToVisual after image scaling

Tags: c#, wpf, image, windows-phone

On the `Windows Phone` I want to get the ellipse coordinates of my `Image`:

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
     <Image x:Name="img" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
         <Image.RenderTransform>
             <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleOld" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
         </Image.RenderTransform>
     </Image>

     <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" x:Name="ellipseArea" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Red" />    
</Grid>
```

`Code`

```
GeneralTransform ellipseCoordinates = ellipseArea.TransformToVisual(img);
Point ellipsePoint = ellipseCoordinates.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

It worked perfectly, but I after I scale the `Image` (using ScaleTransform), I get the wrong coordinates.

How do I get the true coordinates of the Image after scaling?